# Change legend text for factor in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a sample dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(antibiotic = c(0.828080341411847, 1.52002304506738, 
1.31925434545302, 1.66681722567074, 1.17791610945551, 0.950096368502059, 
1.10507733691997, 1.0568193215304, 1.03853131016669, 1.02313195567946, 
0.868629787234043, 0.902126485349154, 1.12005679002801, 1.88261441540084, 
0.137845900627507, 1.07040656448604, 1.41496470588235, 1.30978543173373, 
1.16931780610558, 1.05894439450366, 1.24805122785724, 1.21318238007025, 
0.497310305098053, 0.872362356327429, 0.902584749481137, 0.999731895498823, 
0.907560340983954, 1.05930840957587, 1.40457554864091, 1.09747179272879, 
0.944219456216072, 1.10363111431903, 0.974649273935516, 0.989983064420841, 
1.14784471036171, 1.17232858907798, 1.44675812720393, 0.727078405331282, 
1.36341361598635, 1.06120293299474, 1.06920290856811, 0.711007267992205, 
1.39034247642439, 0.710873996527168, 1.30529753573398, 0.781191310196629, 
0.921788181250106, 0.932214675722466, 0.752289683770589, 0.942392026874501
), year = c(3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 
4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1), imd.decile = c(8, 2, 5, 
5, 4, 3, 2, 8, 6, 4, 3, 6, 9, 2, 5, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2, 9, 11, 2, 
8, 3, 5, 7, 8, 7, 4, 9, 7, 6, 4, 8, 10, 5, 6, 6, 11, 6, 4, 2, 
4, 10, 8, 2, 8, 4, 3)), .Names = c("antibiotic", "year", "imd.decile"
), row.names = c(17510L, 6566L, 24396L, 2732L, 13684L, 28136L, 
1113L, 15308L, 28909L, 21845L, 23440L, 1940L, 8475L, 22406L, 
27617L, 4432L, 3411L, 27125L, 6891L, 6564L, 1950L, 5683L, 25240L, 
5251L, 20058L, 18068L, 5117L, 29066L, 2807L, 24159L, 12309L, 
6044L, 7629L, 2336L, 16583L, 23921L, 17465L, 14911L, 8879L, 13929L, 
17409L, 19421L, 7239L, 11570L, 15283L, 8283L, 16246L, 27950L, 
23723L, 4411L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am graphing antibiotic use against imd.decile (by year)

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = imd.decile, y = antibiotic, col = factor(year))) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = mean, size=1) +
  ylab("My title y")  +
  xlab("My title x") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 2, 0.25))  +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 10, 1)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Year",
                      breaks=c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      labels=c("2013 - 2014", "2014 - 2015", "2015 - 2016", "2016 - 2017"))
p
```

As you can see, I am trying to change my legend text and what the numbers say.

Can someone explain why it's not working? My imd.decile variable in a factor which may be causing some confusion...

Also I want to make the axes title further away from the tick marks - I have previously used "\" - but this isn't working

Comment: `fill != color`

Comment: Thanks @ Henrik - where do I add that command?

Comment: They are saying that `fill` and `color` are different aesthetics. You mapped your data to `color` but then created a `fill` scale. Try using `scale_color_discrete` instead of `scale_fill_discrete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the comments, you're using `scale_fill_discrete` where you should be using `scale_color_discrete`.  I remember the difference between these two by thinking of `fill` for graph objects that take up area (that is, they are 2-dimensional--think bars, polygons, etc) and `color` for graph objects that don't take up area (they are 1-dimensional--think lines, points, etc).  Since you're geom is lines, their is no `fill` to scale discretely.  If you were using a geom like polygons on bars, you could use `scale_color_discrete` but it would only effect the border of the objects.

Try this:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = imd.decile, y = antibiotic, col = factor(year))) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = mean, size=1) +
  ylab("My title y")  +
  xlab("My title x") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 2, 0.25))  +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 10, 1)) +
  scale_color_discrete(name="Year",   # THIS IS THE LINE YOU HAVE TO CHANGE
                  breaks=c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                  labels=c("2013 - 2014", "2014 - 2015", "2015 - 2016", "2016 - 2017"))
p
```